# Не могу разобраться с примером по Java

Tags: ооп, java

Почему можно вызвать:
1)

```
Human human = new Student();
human.run();
```

2)

```
Student student = new Human();
student.run();
```

Я понимаю, что второй пример не запустится, не могу объяснить почему. Объясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вероятно, `Student` наследуется от `Human`. Т.е. объявление класса выглядит как-то так:

```
public class Student extends Human { .... }
```

Т.е. студент является частным случаем человека. очевидно, что все студенты люди, но вот люди - не обязательно студенты.

В первом примере вы объявляете переменную абстрактного (более широкого) типа `Human` и присваиваете ей созданный объект конкретного (более узкого) типа `Student'. Т.е. мы получаем человека, о котором также известно, что он студент, но в контексте переменной`human` мы об этом не знаем.

Во втором примере объявлена переменная типа `Student` и присвоить ей мы можем значение такого же или более узкого типа.  Представьте что у класса `Human` есть поле с фамилией и метод `run`, а у класса `Student` - поле с названием вуза и метод `study`. Если бы присвоение во втором примере было возможно, что бы мы получили при вызове метода `study`? Ведь переменной присвоен объект типа `Human` и никакого метода `study` в нем нет.

Поэтому присвоить переменной можно только объект того же или дочернего типа. Но не родительского.

Comment: спасибо, дошло)